# Help with integral (using integrating by part)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help understanding the equality under the red question mark:
Can you please be as descriptive as possible? :D

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u=t\;\;,\;\;u'=1\\v'=\frac{t}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\,\;\;v=-e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\;\;\;\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\limits_0^\infty te^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}\,\,\frac{t}{\sigma^2}dt=\left.-te^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right|_0^\infty+\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt$$

The first summand on the right above is zero, and for the second one substitute:

$$y:=\frac{t}{\sqrt 2\sigma}\Longrightarrow \sqrt 2\,\sigma\, dy=dt\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}dt=\sqrt 2\,\sigma\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=\sqrt 2\sigma\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sigma\sqrt \pi$$

Comment: how come v=-$e^{\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ ?

Comment: @Mankochka , derivate that wrt $\,t\,$ ...:)

Comment: hmm not sure I understand.. sorry \=

Comment: @Mankochka, use the chain rule (כלל השרשרת): $$\int f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx=e^{f(x)}...$$ This is exactly what we have here!